# Firebase Storage downloads much too slow. Alternatives?

Tags: android, performance, firebase-storage

I have an android app which I want to keep light so I thought I'd store its many mp3 audio clips in Firebase Storage, and about a dozen of these (total size around 200kb) are downloaded the first time a user opens any new recyclerview list before they are playable. It works as intended, problem is the download is incredibly slow and the user waits 20-30s before they can play the files - not acceptable. I've seen other posts complaining of this download speed issue with FB Storage, and one of the few suggestions was to use FB Hosting instead as this is apparently faster. As a newbie I'm struggling with the documentation for this but it seems to be designed to use with web apps, and mine is a mobile app. The other suggestion I saw was to make the files publicly available in FB Storage. I don't particularly want to do this, but would consider it if was my best solution. Is it?

Can FB Hosting be used to store media files for mobile apps? Or should I use another cloud storage service such as Dropbox, whose free 1GB storage would be plenty for me? Could it handle heavy traffic / simultaneous downloads the way I guess FB is designed to? Or should I use a CDN? The app will, hopefully, have users spread globally. I want to use FB anyway for the other tools it provides, but where / how should I store my audio files so they will download quickly? Thanks for advice.

Comment: Obviously those MP3 files seem to be required by your app. In this case (and considering the size of 200KB) I would strongly recommend to include the files into the app. If you want to keep app updates small consider using an obb file or make the whole app a split APK file.

Comment: Thanks. I considered including them in the app, but there are hundreds of such 200kb sets of files, and the app would be approaching 200mb, which I imagine would deter users from trying it out. I just googled obb files and split APKs, but I still think if I can get storage with good download speeds that would be best, and surely must be possible.

Comment: If the total size is 200 Mb why don't you mention this in your question? In any way if Firebase is too slow for you get yourself a server and place the audio files there. BTW app size is relative. I have seen large also e.g. for iOS that contains 900 MB of resources in the app and even worse is that it contains them twice! And the app was not unsuccessfully...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions Robert. I think I found the solution - see answer.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue around 2 years ago, I've moved to Amazon Storage S3, which was much faster than Firebase Storage.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Mohaned. I wonder if you remember if your files were made public on Firebase or not?

Comment: I cannot really remember, but i think it required authentication, not 100% sure.

Answer (score 0):

I made the files publicly available in FB Storage and now I have very fast downloads, so this seems to be the solution. Instructions are here [making data public](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/making-data-public#buckets)